# Creating a contact form for Phonegap apps

Tags: javascript, cordova

I´m building a mobile app in Jquery Mobile using phonegap to compile it to a native app.

Inside that app is a contact form and I can´t get it to work. I  found this solution in stack overflow but even after doing exactly what the solution said, it throws back "Please fill all fields" alert.

Following are the codes i'm using.

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="FirstName">Firstname</label>
        <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="required" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="LastName">Lastname</label>
        <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="required" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input id="Email" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="optional" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="MessageText">Message</label>
        <textarea id="MessageText" name="MessageText" placeholder="required" rows="5" required ></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
// When the document has loaded...
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[type="button"][value="submit"]').click(function() {
    $.post('http://cafedeweb.com/www/handler.php', {


      FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
      LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
      Email: $('#Email').val(),
      MessageText: $('#MessageText').val()

      // HTML function

      }, function (html) {
          // Place the HTML in a astring
          var response=html;

          // PHP was done and email sent
          if (response=="success") {
            alert("Message sent!"); 
          } else {

            // Error postback
            alert("Please fill all fields!"); 
            return false;
          }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post url returns a 404 (http://cafedeweb.com/www/handler.php).
Make sure that you post your form to a webserver with a working php handler.

Comment: this url was used as a filler and the url i have the PHP file will be replaced.  but this piee of code keeps on throwing "Please fill all fields!" even after i'have filled all the fields.

Comment: make sure that your PHP site echo's "success", and nothing else.